# how to make sys.executable be inherited by a subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a main process which creates some child processes using `subprocess.Popen`. Those child processes in turn may or many not create a new processes. I want to be able to use the `sys.executable` from the root process.

Is there any way this can be done without using environment variables which can be passed from process to process?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/path/to/script.py"])`?

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas K said, sys.executable is just a variable that contains the running interpreter. To call it as a process pass it as the first argument to `subprocess.Popen`

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "path/to/script.py"])
```